# Вопрос по удаленному подключению

Tags: delphi

Привет всем!

Такой вопрос: есть ли какие-либо компоненты для Delphi для создания удаленных подключений к ПК, как через интернет, так и для локальной сети. Готовые программы не предлагать, стандартый windows тоже, нужно именно написать самому, или может подскажите ссылку на пример, где можно посмотреть, как это сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

На закладке в Delphi уже есть компоненты Indy Clients: (IdTCPClient, IdUDPClient и т. п.) - для клиентских приложений, на IndyServers - IdTCPServer, IdUDPserver и т. п., естественно, для серверных приложений. Ещё можно дополнительно поставить компонеты, которые по умолчанию не ставятся на закладку Internet. Для этого заходим в пункт меню Component -> Install Packages, жмём кнопку Add, выбираем каталог, гда стоит Delphi (Bin), там выбираем файл dclsockets70.bpl, жмём на Ok (эти компоненты ставятся по умолчанию в Delphi 6, а, начиная, с Delphi 7 - нет).

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, у вас задача сделать RDP-клиент на Delphi. Для этого есть компонент MsRdpClient. На Delphi в сети примеры не находятся, а на других языках встречаются, например, [Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380809(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Что значит удаленных подключений?

Пишите свой клиент и свой сервер и радуйтесь,
да и готовых компонентов для облегчения задачи уйма.
Сформулируйте задачу более конкретно.